# Service timed out using Bing's Maps API in Geopy

Tags: python, bing-maps, geopy

I am trying to use Bing's maps API with Geopy but every time I try to get some coordinates I have the "GeocoderTimedOUT" exception.

```
g=geocoders.Bing('MY_KEY',timeout=5)
place, (lat, lng) = g.geocode("British Museum ", True, None, None)
print "%s: %.5f, %.5f" % (place, lat, lng)
```

Is it a Bing's Maps problem or something in Geopy?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Not an issue with Bing Maps.

Comment: @rbrundritt Looks like no it is working fine without doing any changes, maybe was something temporal. Anyway thank you for the answer.